# Is it possible to read the image using URL in After Effect?

Tags: javascript, xml, csv, after-effects

I am new to after effects, I have read article to change text and price through xml file or csv file. But is it possible to read the image file using any URL script.

So my concept is to make one template contains ProductImg, Title, Description and Price, by reading either xml or csv document,

So next time I will replace the xml file. But I have no idea, how to replace product image.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this, but not as simple as changing text data in a Text Layer.  You have to use ExtendScript, and I would recommend using the [`system.callSystem()`](https://ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/general/system/?highlight=system.callSystem#system-callsystem) method to call a command that would download the remote file on a server somewhere.  You could use something like `wget` or `curl` with the correct parameters to retrieve the file and then import it into After Effects using other ExtendScript methods.

For this type of workflow, I recommend forgoing the use of CSV and XML and just use a cloud-based datastore, like Google Sheets.  For this, you would need [the Templater software extension by Dataclay](https://dataclay.com/templater) to accomplish what you want very easily.  Out-of-the-box, Templater handles [remote footage assets](https://support.dataclay.com/content/concepts/workflow/source_footage_location.htm), you would just need to be sure that the URL to those assets be accessible from the machine that After Effects is running on, and that the URL is a direct link to the asset.